# Why can I not compare a set and immutableset in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Why is it not possible to compare a set and ImmutableSet using the subset operator <= ? E.g. run the following code. What's the problem here? Any help appreciated. I'm using Python 2.7.

```
>>> from sets import ImmutableSet
>>> X = ImmutableSet([1,2,3])
>>> X <= set([1,2,3,4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sets.py", line 291, in issubset
    self._binary_sanity_check(other)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sets.py", line 328, in _binary_sanity_check
    raise TypeError, "Binary operation only permitted between sets"
TypeError: Binary operation only permitted between sets
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a [*`frozenset`* object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead; the [`sets` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) has been deprecated and is not comparable with the built-in types:

```
>>> X = frozenset([1,2,3])
>>> X <= set([1,2,3,4])
True
```

From the documentation for the `sets` module:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The built-in `set`/`frozenset` types replace this module.

If you are stuck with code using the `sets` module, stick to its types exclusively when comparing:

```
>>> from sets import Set, ImmutableSet
>>> Set([1, 2, 3]) <= set([1, 2, 3, 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/sets.py", line 291, in issubset
    self._binary_sanity_check(other)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/sets.py", line 328, in _binary_sanity_check
    raise TypeError, "Binary operation only permitted between sets"
TypeError: Binary operation only permitted between sets
>>> ImmutableSet([1, 2, 3]) <= Set([1, 2, 3, 4])
True
```

Python `set` and `frozenset` do accept any sequence for many of the operators and functions, so *inverting* your test also works:

```
>>> X
frozenset([1, 2, 3])
>>> set([1,2,3,4]) >= X
True
```

The same applies to the `.issubset()` function on the `sets.ImmutableSet` and `sets.Set` classes:

```
>>> X.issubset(set([1,2,3,4]))
True
```

but not mixing the deprecated types and the new built-ins is entirely the best option.